# LEFT JOIN not working with an empty table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a problem getting results from the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS App.ID, UserFeedback.Type FROM App 
LEFT JOIN UserFeedback ON App.ID = UserFeedback.App_ID
```

It's not returning anything, and I am suspecting that it has to do with `UserFeedback` being empty. There is a single row in the `Appointments` table, and it's returned when I use `SELECT * FROM Appointments`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is no `Appointments` table in your query - is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query is fine with an empty join-table, something else must be wrong